# SimpleMembership Presents Login Form to Authenticated User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

Developing an ASP.Net MVC 4 website with SimpleMembership, the Login GET controller is sometimes called even though the user is logged in.  So far this has happened only during development (we're not in QA yet), 
and only after modifying a .cshtml page.  It happens *once in a while* after modifying a .cshtml page, not consistently.

I have added logging to the `Login()` method provided by the template and see that the user is indeed authenticated, and has all roles that a logged-in user should have.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        logger.Error("User " + User.Identity.Name + " is authenticated shown login form.  Roles: " + string.Join(", ", Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)));
        // Temporary work-around: WebSecurity.Logout();
    }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

**Questions**

- What is causing this behavior?
- Can this happen in a production system, e.g. if the app domain is recycled?
- Is the work-around of calling `WebSecurity.Logout()` before returning the login view sound from a security perspective?

Comment: Ive never seen a redirect from the ASP.NET runtime if User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true.  Have you checked the network requests from the browser ?  i.e. is it definitely a redirect for a protected resource ?

Comment: I have not directly observed it in *network requests* (it happens sporadically), but it always happens when refreshing a view that I make a minor edit to (edit the .cshtml).  So, it is always triggered by a refresh of a controller that requires authentication and certain roles.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a user is logged in, instead of User.Identity try this:

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {...}
```

This is true if any user is logged in at the moment. 
Hope this is the answer you were looking for!